React drag and drop to corners
I want to be able to drag a card component to each of the four corners of the screen and get back a value of 1-4. So, you click the card, the corners show 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively, you drag the card to one of the corners, the card disappears, a number is returned, and a new card is shown. How would I implement this with something like dnd-kit? All of the dnd-kit tutorials are for creating sortable lists. Hope this makes sense, thanks.
As stated above, my idea has been to use dnd-kit, but all info on it is just how to use it with lists.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
